# Add non-lamda function to self of Python class

Tags: python, class, lambda

Adding `lambda` expression to `self` of a Python class is easy:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        if x > 0:
            self.eval = lambda x: x
        else:
            self.eval = lambda x: x**2

        return

    def compute(self, y):
        return self.eval(y)
```

In my case, `self.eval` is somewhat more complex such that it doesn't fit into a one-line `lambda`. I need `def`. How can I assign `self.eval` with a `def`ined function though?

For performance reasons, I would like to not store `self.x = x` and not move the `if` into `compute`.

Comment: Just use a def statement ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function anywhere:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        if x > 0:
            def eval(y):
                return y
        else:
            def eval(y):
                return y**2
        self.eval = eval

    def compute(self, y):
        return self.eval(y)
```

Comment: It's not about `self.x = x`, but the possible `if` in `compute`.

Comment: Gotcha, just misunderstood you there.

Answer (score 2):

[Python functions are first class objects](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/first-class-functions-python/). You can assign any function to a variable:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        if x > 0:
            self.eval = self.method1
        else:
            self.eval = self.method2


    def method1(self, x):
        return x


    def method2(self, x):
        return x * x


    def compute(self, y):
        return self.eval(y)


f1 = Foo(1)
print(f1.compute(10)) # 10 (method1)

f2 = Foo(-1)
print(f2.compute(10)) # 100 (method2)
```

Answer (score 1):

At least in Python 3 it is trivial to add a method to an existing class. Just look at the following code:

```
>>> class A:
    val = 2     # declare a class variable (will be the default value

>>> def func(self, x):       # declare a function that will be added as a method
    return self.val * x

>>> A.compute = func         # add the compute method to class A
>>> a = A()                  # create an instance
>>> a.val                    # control the value of the member
2
>>> a.compute(3)             # use the added method
6
>>> a.val=3                  # change the value of the variable for the specific instance
>>> a.compute(4)             # control that the new variable value is used
12
```